# Pega Child to parent data propagation

Tags: data-transform, pega

How can I copy child data to parent case by using data transform?

If somebody can give a step-wise solution.

I've used a data transform and update shape in child case, it is still not working.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please see how to ask properly https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Configure your update shape as follows. `.pxCoverInsKey` will refer to parent case. Note that you can use **any** instance key here - other cases such children or siblings would work as well.

[image: Update case shape]

Then, create a new data transform. Add references to both parent and child cases under Pages & Classes.

[image: case page references]

Finally, set the appropriate properties. In my case, that's just a single field: `.Name`. `pyWorkCover` now refers to the parent case, whereas `pyWorkPage` is the child.

[image: data transform, setting parent data from child]

Source: https://collaborate.pega.com/discussion/propagating-data-back-parent-case