# Pega transfer between two siblings

Tags: siblings, data-transform, pega

I am trying to copy the page list from one child case to another child case i.e between siblings.
I've tried using data transform and update shape but it doesn't seem working.
What are the other ways?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pega Child to parent data propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63360994/pega-child-to-parent-data-propagation)

Answer (score 0):

You will need the pyID/pzInsKey of the second sibling in order to acheive this.

Ex. if you have these 3 cases: Parent-1, Child-1 & Child-2
If Child-1 wants to update Child-2, you will need to run an activity to search for Child-2 and open the case to copy the data.